# Structurizing issue MySQL and Python

Tags: php, python, mysql, data-structures

Okay, so my issue is a planning one rather than an actual 'error'-type problem and I come to you guys for your thoughts on how best to structurise my project!

**Here's what I'm working with.**

I have a MQTT server (v3.1.1 I believe) running, to which devices connect. The server also has a Python (v2.7) script running that will dish out commands to which the connected devices have to respond/run.

There are a few constants and a lot of variables. They are as follows:

1. the devices have a serial number (which is communicated upon connecting to the MQTT server) which is unique.
2. the device IP (even the IP of the MQTT server) is dynamic. How do they connect you ask? It's always xx.xx.xx.250. So I have them search for their subnet and connect to .250 on that.
3. the devices will be given (sort of registration process) an ID (called: REGID) to which they can be recognized (as a serial number is too hard to remember) sadly this isn't set in stone, these could be integers (001) or a variation with numbers (A01) or just text (snoopy).

As a result, my MySQLdb looks like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+----+--------+
+ ID + REGID + STATUS + IP + SERIAL +
+----+-------+--------+----+--------+
```

**Here's the dilemma:**

I'm trying to store and keep accurate information on a MySQLdb to be displayed on a page of these devices.

When a device logs in, it checks into MQTT and it's 'IP', and 'serial' are noted. It's 'serial' and 'status' are written into the DB (UPDATE WHERE IP=)

On the other hand, when it's noted serial matches one that is already in the DB I would assume it's registered under 'regid' and only the 'status' is updated.

*Problem with this*: when it's IP changes (for whatever reason) I will end up with duplicates, something that I simply can't have, is there a way to guard against this?

**I have thought of:**

Making 2 tables instead: one with the 'serial' and 'regid' (table: registration) and one with the 'ip', 'status' and 'serial' (table: devices) although this also does not guard me against duplicates...

Any help and/or suggestions would be REALLY appreciated because I can't think of a solution!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Problem with this: when it's IP changes (for whatever reason) I will end up with duplicates, something that I simply can't have, is there a way to guard against this?*

You only need one unique key which is the serial.  When you find that the serial is already in the database table update the status **and** the IP.  That way you will always have the current IP.  If you need record of the old IP create another table which is a history table.  This history table can have multiple entries for the same serial number.